# SciTE Regex, Match expression between x and y times eg \w*{x,y}

Tags: regex, scite

How can I use SciTE to match a word character between 1 and 7 times?

normally it would be

```
\w{1,7}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it can be done that way in SciTE.

Maybe: \w\w?\w?\w?\w?\w?\w?

Comment: Maybe add a \< at the start and a \> at the end. If matching whole words was the intent.

Comment: Actually the question mark doesn't seem to be supported either: http://www.nabble.com/Regex-search-replace:-%22-%22-does-not-work-td11981373.html

Answer (score 1):

It does not support that syntax, you can view the docs [here](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html).
As activa said, the only way to do it seems to be \w\w?\w?\w?\w?\w?\w?